Understanding Adversary's Advantage for Target Key Recovery in Ideal Cipher Model
In the ideal cipher model, a block cipher is modeled by a different, independent random permutation for every key.
Let $$ \mathcal{A}_{q}^{\text{IC-EKS}} $$ be a ( q )-query exhaustive key-search adversary in the ideal cipher model.
and $\textit{IC-TKR-advantage}$ of $\mathcal{A}$ for key-length $k$ and block-length $\ell$ be
$$
\text{Adv}^{\text{IC-TKR}}_{k,\ell}(\mathcal{A}) = \Pr \left[ \text{IC-TKR}^{\mathcal{A}}_{k,\ell} \text{ outputs } 1 \right].
$$
Then, we have the following.
$$
\text{Adv}^{\text{IC-TKR}}_{k,\ell}(\mathcal{A}_{1}^{\text{IC-EKS}}) \geq 2^{\ell - k} \left( 1 - \left( 1 - \frac{1}{2^\ell} \right)^{2^k} \right).
$$
How do I prove this? How to approach proving these kinds of inequalities?

Let's unpack the inequality:
$$
\text{Adv}^{\text{IC-TKR}}_{k,\ell}(\mathcal{A}_{1}^{\text{IC-EKS}}) \geq 2^{\ell - k} \left( 1 - \left( 1 - \frac{1}{2^\ell} \right)^{2^k} \right).
$$
Firstly we assume independence and uniformity for all relevant random variables. Since given bitlength $n$ each bitstring of length $n$ is equally likely with probability $2^{-n},$ we note that
$$
\left( 1 - \frac{1}{2^\ell} \right)^{2^k} 
$$
is the probability that a given $\ell$ bit string is not guessed correctly in $2^k$ independent trials (each guessing a given key value). Then,
$$
\left( 1 - \left( 1 - \frac{1}{2^\ell} \right)^{2^k} \right).
$$
is the probability that a given $\ell$ bit string is actually guessed correctly in those trials.
There are $2^\ell$ blocks and $2^k$ keys, so if the two are not the same, due to uniformity, on average $2^\ell/2^k$ blocks correspond to each key, accounting for the factor $2^{\ell-k}$ in front.

We are in the situation where we have a single pair of matched plain and cipher blocks. The advantage is the probability that probability that the adversary selects the target key from all keys that map this block of plain to this block of cipher. Apart from the target key, under the IC model, other keys have a $p=2^{-\ell}$ chance of satisfying the condition.
We write $n$ for the number of non-target keys satisfying the condition and note that $n$ is distributed binomially with parameters $2^k-1$ and $p$. If $n$ non-target keys exist, then the probability of selecting the target key is $1/(n+1)$. Thus
\begin{eqnarray*}\mathrm{Advantage}&=&\sum_{n=0}^{2^k-1}\frac1{n+1}\binom{2^k-1}np^n(1-p)^{2^k-n-1}\\
&=&\frac1{p2^k}\sum_{n=0}^{2^k-1}\binom{2^k}{n+1}p^{n+1}(1-p)^{2^k-(n+1)}\end{eqnarray*}
Now note that by the binomial theorem
$$\sum_{n=0}^{2^k-1}\binom{2^k}{n+1}p^{n+1}(1-p)^{2^k-(n+1)}=\sum_{m=1}^{2^k}\binom{2^k}mp^m(1-p)^{2^k-m}=1-(1-p)^{2^k}.$$
Substituting in the definition of $p$, we now have
$$\mathrm{Advantage}=2^{\ell-k}\left(1-\left(1-\frac1{2^\ell}\right)^{2^k}\right)$$
as required. (Note that the expression is an equality rather than an inequality).
